Geometric construction of common tangent to two conics
I attempt to understand the geometric construction of common tangent to two conics on this site.
Two conics $C_0,C_1$ intersect at four points $P,O,M,N$.

Take arbitrary point $S_{12}$ on the line $PM$.
Let $Q_{12}$ be the pole of the line $PM$ wrt the conic $C_0$.
Let the line $S_{12}Q_{12}$ intersect $C_0$ at two points $T_{12},U_{12}$.
Let $R_{12}$ be the pole of the line $PM$ wrt the conic $C_1$.
Let the line $S_{12}R_{12}$ intersect $C_1$ at two points $V_{12},W_{12}$.
Let $T_1$ be the intersection of $U_{12}W_{12}$ with $V_{12}T_{12}$.

Similarly, construct $T_4$:

Take arbitrary point $S_{34}$ on the line $MO$.
Let $Q_{34}$ be the pole of the line $MO$ wrt the conic $C_0$.
Let the line $S_{34}Q_{34}$ intersect $C_0$ at two points $T_{34},U_{34}$.
Let $R_{34}$ be the pole of the line $MO$ wrt the conic $C_1$.
Let the line $S_{34}R_{34}$ intersect $C_1$ at two points $V_{34},W_{34}$.
Let $T_4$ be the intersection of $T_{34}W_{34}$ with $U_{34}V_{34}$.

How do you prove that the line $T_1T_4$ is a common tangent to two conics $C_0$ and $C_1$?
Equivalently, to prove $T_1$ is the intersection of two common tangents to $C_0$ and $C_1$?

Maybe related to Dual of Desargues’ involution theorem?

This answer might be helpful.
